# Firebase authentication in a separate class android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an android app with firebase authentication. 
I need access to the signed-in user from multiple activities in my app.
Thats why I thought of implementing the firebase api in a different class(instead of, in every onCreate activity) and store a "UserInfo" object which I can read from anywhere.

This ensures Firebase api is run only once. But I noticed android will spawn a new thread which will communicate with firebase, and my main thread will continue executing. As a result, I never get a call inside "onAuthStateChanged" and my userInfo object is never initialized. 
Does anyone know how to handle this?

```
public class AuthClass {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

UserInfo userInfo;

AuthClass()
{
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void getUser()
{
    String userStatus = "NONE"
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    userStatus = "SIGNED_IN"
                    userInfo = new UserInfo(user.getUid(), user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    userStatus = "SIGNED_OUT";
                }
            }
        };
}
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    AuthClass authClass = new AuthClass();
    AuthClass.UserInfo userInfo = authClass.getUser(); // userInfo is always NULL
}
}
```

Comment: In `onAuthStateChanged` `user.getUid()` and `user.getEmail()` are null?

Comment: extend your mainactivity with Auth class that would be very easy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to move the authentication in your activity class.

You are getting null because in `onAuthStateChanged()` method from `AuthClass` class you are creating an object of `UserInfo` and in `MainActivity` you are trying to get data from another object. That's way is always null. In order to solve this problem you have 2 ways.

1. To use the data in another activity you need to use an `intent` to store data. In this way you'll be able to use data between activiteis like this.

In the FirstActivity:

```
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
String email = firebaseUser.user.getEmail();
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
intent.putExtra("email", email);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the SecondActivity:

```
String uid = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("uid");
String email = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("email");
```

You can also use in stead of Strings, the entire object like this:

In the FirstActivity:

```
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
String email = firebaseUser.user.getEmail();
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(uid, email);
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("userInfo", userInfo);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the SecondActivity:

```
UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userInfo");
String uid = userInfo.getUid();
String email = userInfo.getEmail();
```

In this case don't forget to add `UserInfo implements Serializable` inteface to your `UserInfo` class.

Another approach is to use `SharedPreferences`.

Hope it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: I implemented this one. Its easy as of now since I have only two arguments to pass. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need a interface for this.
Modify the `AuthClass` like this.

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

UserInfo userInfo;

public interface AuthListener{
 void userAuthChanged(FirebaseUser user);
}

AuthListener authListener;

public void setAuthListener(AuthListener al){
 this.authListener = al;
}

AuthClass()
{
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void getUser()
{
  String userStatus = "NONE"
  mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                userStatus = "SIGNED_IN"
                userInfo = new UserInfo(user.getUid(), user.getEmail());
                authListener.userAuthChanged(user);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                userStatus = "SIGNED_OUT";
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

In your activity do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

AuthClass authClass = new AuthClass();
authClass.setAuthListener(new AuthClass.AuthListener(){
   @Override
   public void userAuthChanged(FirebaseUser user){

   }
  });

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get null is obviously because your Activity wants to get the UserInfo, while it is not ready so it returns null. You may use an interface for instance,`CustomAuthListener` as follows:

```
public class AuthClass {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

UserInfo userInfo;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private final CustomAuthListener customAuthListener;

AuthClass(CustomAuthListener cal)
{
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    customAuthListener = cal;  
}

public void getUser()
{
    String userStatus = "NONE"
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    userStatus = "SIGNED_IN"
                    customAuthListener.authSuccessfull(new UserInfo(user.getUid(), user.getEmail()));
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    userStatus = "SIGNED_OUT";
                }
            }
        };
   public interface CustomAuthListener {
        void authSuccessfull(UserInfo userInfo);   
   }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    AuthClass authClass = new AuthClass(new CustomAuthHandler());
}

public CustomAuthHandler implemen AuthClass.CustomAuthListener{
    @Override
    public void authSuccessfull(UserInfo userInfo){
          //Do whatever you want with userinfo
    }  
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **mAuthListener** inside the constructor. That way it will works fine.

Here is an example of how I implement.

```
public class CurrentUser {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    public CurrentUser() {
        this.mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        this.currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
                    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                }else{
                    currentUser = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        if(currentUser!=null){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

> Not sure if this is the right way but this does the job for me.